# Why variable lose type if init with null in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
type State = {
    name: string
}

let initialState: State | null = null
```

initialState type is null

I have to use cast

```
let initialState = null as null | State
```

Then initialState type is null | State

I prefer use declaring rather then casting.

Does anyone know why only casting would work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> initialState type is null

No, [the type is `State | null`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQVtQHbwFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLXAcwwF8MMAbCYKW64a+VuIhKwESKAB88AV1asoqXDNYYA9CuwA9APxA), which is the type you've used in the type declaration. The initial **value** is `null`, but the type is `State | null`.

To use `initialState`'s `name`, you first have to guarantee that `initialState` is not `null` (since `null.name` would be an error), which you typically do with a type guard:

```
if (initialState) {
    // You can use `initialState.name` here, the type has been
    // narrowed to just `State`
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQVtQHbwFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLXAcwwF8MMAbCYKW64a+VuIhKwESKAB88AV1asoqXDNYYA9CuwA9APwtqAMygAKALKIAFgDpK8XABMA9gUMBKKAB4oABgsBWV5hwuXB4+AVEUdHwiUgAiCAAPQjB2GMYAbiZdA0NuXn5BJH8sHABje1wye3YLVns6HOC8sKELKIhnDMC1QJ6obSYoCFYyaADS8srq2vqAA1zQgugAd3gyaVkZjqYgA)

Or you can use a type guard function, or a type assertion function if you need this in a place you **know** `initialState` is not `null`.

You can also use optional chaining:

```
const name = initialState?.name;
```

...but note that the type of `name` in that would be `undefined | string`, since if `initialState` is `null`, `initialState?.name` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks

Comment: `let initialState: State | null = null`
`initialState // hint will be: let initialState: null`
If I write

`let initialState = null as null | State`
`initialState // hint will be: let initialState: State | null`

Comment: @RalphChen - Please see the first link in the answer above, that's simply incorrect. The type of `initialState` will be `State | null`, not `null`.

Comment: I edited the file. Please check. If hover at line 8, the type hint will be null. I knew line 14 will be State | null. Because of this behavior, line 25 will throw error.

Comment: @RalphChen - I can't tell you why whatever it is that's showing you that hint is showing you that, but again, if I take your code and copy-and-paste it into a TypeScript environment (for instance, [the first link in the answer](https://tsplay.dev/mx6GXw)), the type of the variable is `State | null`, not `null`. This is extremely basic TypeScript. There is no problem assigning a `State` object to the variable ([example](https://tsplay.dev/wQegAw)), because its type allows it. So whatever that hint is meant to show you, it's not showing you the TypeScript type of that variable.

Comment: But more to the point: What's the problem you're trying to solve? I could see some tool being able to tell, from static analysis, that `initialState` has the value `null` at that point (**not** the type `null`), but there's no problem assigning a `State` to it, so...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When I create variable as initial state for redux slice, if I use let initialState: State | null = null, I will get warning. However if I write const initialState = null as null | State. It works fine.

Comment: @RalphChen - Sounds like an issue with some other tool, not TypeScript.